# Calculating the surface state with Wannier tools

Tags: density-functional-theory, band-structure, surfaces, tight-binding, wannier90

Currently I met a problem when I calculate the surface state of a topologically non-trivial thin film system. I did a DFT calculation and fit the result with wannier function. The fitting looks pretty good around the band gap region. Then I use tight binding to calculate the surface state. I found that the band structure along -X -> G -> X  didn't preserve the time reversal symmetry (E(k) is not equal to E(-k) and it become a trivial edge state. For a system without magnetisation and external B-field, the time reversal symmetry can be preserved. So the relation of E(k) = E(-k) should be always true? I can't find any reason for my result. Is there any people who did similar things before and have some suggestion ?

For the band gap region:
[image]

The surface state was shown in below:
[image]
For the notation of R in the surface state plot, it is -X. So it is the plot from -X -> G -> X. and it didn't contain the time reversal symmetry.

Comment: +1 perhaps you could share a plot to show what you are seeing, which may help identify the problem?

Comment: @ProfM I have already uploaded a plot for a 5atomic layers system. For other atomics layers system, the surface state are still very messy which provided no information for the material. This material was provide to have a non-trivial edge state in bulk. I have already verify the result. But I found that the result of the edge state depends on the fitting of the wannier function. For my wannier function even though the spread is a bit large, as you can see the fitted result is still very good. But it give a non-sense surface state result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wannier90 might not be good at preserving the symmetry. But they probably include a few new methods to enforce symmetry in Wannier90.v.3.1.0. Maybe you can check this.
http://www.wannier.org/features/

Also, WannierTools can symmetrize the hr.dat, but from my personal experience it sometimes gives you worse results than the original hr.dat.
http://www.wanniertools.com/symmetrization.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. May I ask a few more follow up question. Like you said, the wannier90 may not good at preserving the symmetry. But from the result I got, did I do anything wrong which may cause this mistake? Because by the direct inspection, the fitting is very good, even though each Wannier function is a bit larger than the Lattice constant. Is this an acceptable result ?

Comment: fitting is definitely *NOT* good to check symmetry... Maybe spin texture is better